# Grab end of url server side

Tags: html, http-status-code-404

If I have a user accessing my site for example: www.example.com/testpage.html, is there any way to grab the "testpage.html" as a string if the testpage.html doesn't exist? (I want to make custom 404 error messages..Basically I want when the user goes to a page that doesnt exist, say "This page [pagename] doesnt exist" and display a search result with the pagename as the query.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally if you want to do anything useful with dynamic content, you're going to need some sort of interpreted language to provide the logic. As you did not specify, I assume you'll be using PHP.

In the case of PHP, you have access to the [$_SERVER superglobal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) which, among other bits, exposes **REQUEST_URI** (e.g. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) which is exactly what you are looking for. You can then build some logic in your PHP script around this variable to do actions based on specific matched URIs.

Example:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/testpage.html") {
  // Do something here
}
```

You could, of course, also get fancy with [regular expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), case statements, etc.

Comment: Where would this php script be stored?

Comment: http://us.php.net/manual/en/install.php would probably be a good start. :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your real question is "How do I make a custom 404 page", yes?  That's going to be web server dependent.

As to extracting parts of the URL, if you're using PHP then you want the [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.  In Perl, you'd use the [`URI`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/) module